# Labels of radio buttons on Job Preferences page not clickable

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

Tiny stuff for the win!

While I was updating my preferences for other reasons, I stumbled over my Job Preferences page and found that these labels (freehand red circle) do have the pointer cursor but don't "click" the radio button next to them.

[image: circles around labels of job preferences]

Would be neat if they would work that way (adding an id to the radiobuttons equal to their name and a for to the label appears to be sufficient).

Just for sake of completeness: Windows 10, Firefox 72.0.1

Comment: I repro on Chrome under Windows 10. Seems like an easy, obvious fix.